# Does “fileReplacements” option works with react native using nx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, dotenv, nrwl-nx

I have to load different environment files based on different commands, so I did this in nx project.json of react native mobile project

```js
 "build-android": {
      "executor": "@nx/react-native:build-android",
      "outputs": [
        "{projectRoot}/android/app/build/outputs/bundle",
        "{projectRoot}/android/app/build/outputs/apk"
      ],
      "configurations": {
        "dev": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "apps/mobile/src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "apps/mobile/src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
  },
```

I ran nx build-android mobile --configuration=dev

But I got an error shown in the image

> [nx build error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNwfS.png)

This works in react but not working in react native.

Can anybody help in this ?